# Почему Webpack не собирает font-awesome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, импорт, зависимости

Использую популярный в гайдах для новичков метод импорта стилей в приложение:

```
import './img/favicon.ico';
import 'normalize.css'; //  Установлено в "dependencies"
import 'flexboxgrid2';  //  Установлено в "dependencies"
import 'font-awesome';  //  Установлено в "dependencies"
import './scss/main.scss';
```

Первые два пакета стилей разрешаются в node_modules и собираются без вопросов, а на font-awesome выдаёт это:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome' in 'C:\...\...\...

Я уже было решил указать вручную путь до причинного css или scss файла в директории установки, но подумал, что это, наверно, не здорово. Хотя бы потому, что не так красиво. Кроме того, судя по результатам беглого поиска, подружить webpack и  fontawesome - задача в принципе нетривиальная.
Так что, собственно, мне нужно для этого знать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так тебе надо импортировать не сам пакет, а только .css файл, который там. Ну и проверь подхватывает ли он еще и сами файлы шрифта.

`import "font-awesome/scss/fontawesome.scss";`